# How long does the green "new!" icon stay next to new Lists?

Tags: custom-list

I created a new Custom List and Task List in SharePoint 2013. How long does the green "new!" box stay next to the newly installed List?
Thanks
[image: photo of new list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its depend upon the settings, By default it is for 2 days. You can use the following PowerShell to check the current settings.

```
Get-SPWebApplication https://web app url | ft DisplayName, Url, DaysToShowNewIndicator
```

If you want to change this setting then use the following code:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebAppication -Identity:http://webappurl
$wa.DaysToShowNewIndicator = {SomeInteger}
$wa.Update()
```

This is web app level settings.
Read more here: https://danmyhre.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/new-indicator-in-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-number-of-days-to-show/

Answer (score 1):

Two full days, then until the next midnight.

Answer (score 1):

The default setting on the web application is to display this icon for 2 days. If you want to customize this, you can easily do it.

See the below command to set the number of days to 10 days for the "New" icon to be displayed for items on a Web site-

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -pv 10
```

(Note: You can substitute **-pn** for **-propertyname** and **-pv** for -**propertyvalue**.)

Reference - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287681(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Default time is 2 days,

You can check it by below stsadm command.

```
stsadm -o getproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -url
```

To set time,

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -pv 'Days To Show'
```